# Custom normals are not working in render, only in viewport

Tags: rendering, normals, vertex-groups

Using 3.6.0

My custom normal split geo data is working fine in viewport in render view, but when I go to render the image through the actual renderer it doesn't show the custom normals? Notice the diagonal line in the rendered frame. Any ideas?

[image: viewport]
[image: render]
[image: Shader I'm using]

Comment: Hello please show your shader editor

Comment: Do you have a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on the object with different _Level_ setting for _Viewport_ and _Render_?

Comment: @moonboots Heres the shader now added I'm using, I've tried removing the bump maps, even loading a basic BSDF and using straight colour, it does the same thing, so doubt it's shader based.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Nah no multi-res or any modifiers accept the armature.

Comment: Small update, turning off autosmooth does remove the weird diagonal line etc, but it also gets rid of my custom split normals, either way I can't seem to replicate the render look in viewport anyway I can. The degrees of the auto smooth stays greyed out on or off which is odd too.

Comment: FIXED: I don't know what changed, but the blender 4.0 release has fixed it. Might have been a bug maybe.